# How to compare array to a number for if statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement

`H0` is an array (`[1:10]`), and `H` is a single number (`5`).

How to compare every element in `H0` with the single number `H`?

For example in

```
if H0>H 
   do something
else
   do another thing
end
```

MATLAB always does the other thing.

Answer (score 9):

`if` requires the following statement to evaluate to a scalar true/false. If the statement is an array, the behaviour is equivalent to wrapping it in `all(..)`.

If your comparison results in a logical array, such as

```
H0  = 1:10;
H   = 5;
test = H0>H;
```

you have two options to pass `test` through the `if`-statement:

(1) You can aggregate the output of `test`, for example you want the if-clause to be executed when `any` or `all` of the elements in `test` are true, e.g.

```
if any(test)
  do something
end
```

(2) You iterate through the elements of `test`, and react accordingly

```
for ii = 1:length(test)
   if test(ii)
      do something
   end
end
```

Note that it may be possible to vectorize this operation by using the logical vector `test` as index.

**edit**

If, as indicated in a comment, you want `P(i)=H0(i)^3 if H0(i)<H`, and otherwise `P(i)=H0(i)^2`, you simply write

```
 P = H0 .^ (H0<H + 2)
```

Comment: I used 'for' but there was a problem
for ii = 1:length(test)
if test(ii)
P=H0
end
end
because H0 is a an array of 10 numbers I got 10*10 values of P not just 10
I know I'm so beginner but any way thank you

Comment: @Nawar: you have to index properly, for example `P(ii)=H0(ii)`. However,if you want to apply the function you mentioned in the other comment, then my edit will allow you to do this in one simple line.

Comment: Can you please put up the last solution to the top of your answer?

Answer (score 2):

@Jonas's nice answer at his last line motivated me to come up with a version using logical indexing.

Instead of

```
for i=1:N
  if H0(i)>H
     H0(i)=H0(i)^2;
  else
     H0(i)=H0(i)^3;
  end
end
```

you can do this

```
P = zeros(size(H0)); % preallocate output
test = H0>H;

P(test) = H0(test).^2; % element-wise operations 
                       % on the elements for which the test is true

P(~test) = H0(~test).^3; % element-wise operations 
                         % on the elements for which the test is false
```

Note that this is a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway take a look at this: using `ismemeber()` function. Frankly not sure how do you expect to compare. Either greater than, smaller , equal or within as a member. So my answer might not be yet satisfying to you. But just giving you an idea anyway.

```
H0 = [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20];
H  = [10];
ismember(H,H0)
IF (ans = 1) then
// true
else
//false
end
```

**Update Answer**

This is **super bruteforce method** - just use it explain. You are better off with any other answers given here than what I present. Ideally what you need is to rip off greater/lower values into two different vectors with `^3` processing - I assume... :)

```
H0 = [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20];
H  = [10];

H0(:)
ans = 
     0
     2
     4
     6
     8
     10
     12
     14
     16
     18
     20
```

Function `find` returns indices of all values in `H0` greater than 10 values in a linear index.

```
X = find(H0>H)
X = 
     7
     8
     9
     10
     11
```

Function `find` returns indices of all values in `H0` lower than 10 in a linear index.

```
Y = find(H0<H)
Y =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
```

If you want you can access each element of `H0` to check greater/lower values or you can use the above matrices with indices to rip the values off `H0` into two different arrays with the arithmetic operations.

```
G = zeros(size(X)); // matrix with the size = number of values greater than H
J = zeros(size(Y)); // matrix with the size = number of values lower than H

for i = 1:numel(X)
     G(i) = H0(X(i)).^3
end

G(:)
ans =

      1728
      2744
      4096
      5832
      8000

for i = 1:numel(Y)
     J(i) = H0(Y(i)).^2
end

J(:)
ans =

      0
      4
     16
     36
     64
    100
```

Comment: I want to compare every element on the array is less than the number or otherwise so if H0<H P=H0^3, else P=H0^2